# redhawksdr Using Redhawk persona devices, I need a 'how to'

Tags: redhawksdr, persona

I am looking into persona devices as described in Appendix G of the Redhawk manual.

Is there a detailed "how to" for this anywhere?

In my scenario my 'Programmable Device' would be a Redhawk FEI device that interfaces with a kernel API that controls tuners, fans, gps, buttons and LCD displays. I would like to break this out into three or four persona devices that interface with the main FEI Device.

Thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you head to [Geon's github](https://github.com/geontech) and look at the [RFNoC_ProgrammableDevice](https://github.com/Geontech/RFNoC_ProgrammableDevice) and [RFNoC_DefaultPersona](https://github.com/Geontech/RFNoC_DefaultPersona), you can get an idea of how these Devices interact with one another. It should be noted that these Devices are still under development. Unfortunately, the manual appendix you mentioned and these examples are really the closest thing to a "how to" there is right now.

That being said, this pattern is generally reserved for FPGAs, with the programmable Device controlling access to the programmable hardware (and FEI functionality, if present) and the persona(s) controlling access to specific bit file capabilities. If you're not interacting with an FPGA, then the pattern will most likely be more trouble than it's worth to obtain modularity.